# iTunes or other RSS/podcast reader that can retrieve whole podcast, I.E. transversing pages?

Tags: itunes, podcasts, rss

I listen to a podcast* which is in Atom RSS 2.0 format.

I subscribed with iTunes, the feed presents 5 entries in each page, and pages are accessible by appending `?page=n`, n being the page number.

But iTunes doesn't seem to see farther than the first page, is there an option for iTunes to retrieve the whole podcast instead of just the first page?

Is there another RSS/podcast reader that can?

* http://venganzasdelpasado.com.ar/posts.rss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know of an app that supports this.

Perhaps you could add more than one feed:

- `http://venganzasdelpasado.com.ar/posts.rss`
- `http://venganzasdelpasado.com.ar/posts.rss?page=2`

And have iTunes handle it that way?

Alternatively, you could create your own RSS feed based on the website’s HTML, rather than use the one the website is offering which is limited to 5 items. That way, you could have more entries in the feed. This can be done using [FeedWeaver](http://feedweaver.net/), a free online web app.

Comment: Well, the feed has more than 250 pages, so I'll end up with 250 different podcasts, obviously not good.  
FeedWeaver also can't handle this.  
I guess I can make a program that would do the job of gathering all pages in a single feed, but I was hoping there was already a software that could do it.